# Custom Attribute in Style tags in SXA <link rel=preload>

Tags: sxa

Our site is currently implemented in SXA 1.5 and Sitecore 8.2 instance.

We generate the styles through the following code in our Main Layout file:

```
AssetLinks assetLinks = AssetLinksGenerator.GenerateLinks(new ThemesProvider());

  @foreach (string style in assetLinks.Styles)
  {
    @Html.Raw(style)
  }
```

Thus we have the following generated link for Styles (Style optimization set as Optimized in Page Content in SXA)

```
<link href="/-/media/themes/mysite/styles/optimized-min.css?t=20190819T075414Z" rel="stylesheet" />
```

Now there is a requirement from the SEO team to add an attribute to the above CSS tag as:

```
<link rel="preload" href="/-/media/themes/mysite/styles/optimized-min.css?t=20190819T075414Z" as="style">
```

How can we achieve this customized tag in SXA?

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if there is any clean way to enrich the SXA code which generates `<link>` tags, but you can always just use `String.Replace` like that:

```
style.Replace("<link", "<link rel=\"preload\"")
```

This will make sure that `rel="preload"` attribute is added to your tag.

You can add `as="style"` or any other attributes in the same way:

```
@Html.Raw(style.Replace("<link", "<link rel=\"preload\""))
```

Answer (score 1):

`AssetLinksGenerator` service is responsible for generating links to scripts and styles. You have two options:

1. Override that service and modify `GenerateAssetLinks()` method like more or less this: [image] 
   Unfortunately, this service is not registered in the DI container (I think it should, we need to change it) and you will need to modify `SxaLayout.cshtml`:[image]
2. Go to the `SxaLayout.cshtml` and modify the list of links directly there without need to override `AssetLinksGenerator`.

In both cases, you need to modify the `SxaLayout.cshtml` view. Keep in mind that this file will be overridden while upgrading SXA.